# R Dplyr top_n does not work when used within function

Tags: r, dplyr

My dplyr function looks like this

```
convert_to_top5_df=function(df)

{
  require(dplyr)
  require(lazyeval)
  require(tidyr)

  df %>%
  filter(!is.na(SVM_LABEL_QOL)) %>%         
  select(globalsegment,Account,SVM_LABEL_QOL) %>%
  group_by(globalsegment,Account) %>%  
  summarise_(QoL=interp(~round(sum(SVM_LABEL_QOL %in% 'QoL')/n(),2))) %>%
  ungroup(globalsegment,Account) %>%
  arrange(desc(QoL)) %>%
  interp(~top_n(5,wt = "QoL"))

}
```

I added the `interp` argument, as I thought the problem was due to `lazyeval`
However this is not the case.

Using the function below (no `interp` for `top_n`), I get a result, however I do not see the top 5 results as desired.

Reading other stackoverflow posts, I understand that this has to do with `ungroup`, but not sure how to implement this.

```
convert_to_top5_df=function(df)

{
  require(dplyr)
  require(lazyeval)
  require(tidyr)

  df %>%
  filter(!is.na(SVM_LABEL_QOL)) %>%
  select(globalsegment,Account,SVM_LABEL_QOL) %>%
  group_by(globalsegment,Account) %>%  
  summarise_(QoL=interp(~round(sum(SVM_LABEL_QOL %in% 'QoL')/n(),2))) %>%
  ungroup(globalsegment,Account) %>%
  arrange(desc(QoL)) %>%
  top_n(5,wt = "QoL")

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My solutionn, remove the inverted quotes from `QoL` and add an additional argument to `arrange`:

```
#Function to convert dataframe for pie chart analysis (Global)
convert_to_top5_df=function(df)

{

require(dplyr)
require(lazyeval)
require(tidyr)

df %>%
filter(!is.na(SVM_LABEL_QOL)) %>%         
select(globalsegment,Account,SVM_LABEL_QOL) %>%
group_by(globalsegment,Account) %>%  
summarise_(QoL=interp(~round(sum(SVM_LABEL_QOL %in% 'QoL')/n(),2))) %>%
top_n(5,QoL) %>%
arrange(globalsegment,desc(QoL))

}
```

If anyone's got a more efficient way, please share